# Use an anchor on my form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, anchor

I would like to anchor a form in my codebehind.  Despite my searches, the code I'm using does not seem to work:

```
this.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
```

Does anyone know why it's not working properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms do not have `Anchor` or `Dock` properties available to use unless they are inside a container (with `TopLevel=false;`).

If you want to have your form act as a "side bar" like application, you can try using the [SHAppBarMessage function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Also this [Application Desktop ToolBars](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3728/C-does-Shell-Part-3) project could help.